# Пунктуация в предложении с союзом «за то... что»

Tags: запятые, союзы, и

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как будет правильно и почему?

*Извините за то, что долго отвечали(**,**) и за то, что привезли не то.*

Answer (score 1):

Правильным будет такой вариант.

**Извините за то, что долго отвечали, и за то, что привезли не то.**

Придаточное предложение должно закрываться запятой в данном случае, ведь союз "и" соединяет два однородных местоимения "то".